# Rails radio button passing true and false as strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, this is how I am creating a radio button in my Rails application:

```
        <div class="form-group row">
          <%= form.label :exclusion, class: "col-sm-3 col-form-label", for: 'scope_exclusion' %>
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9 col-12 pt-2 pl-3">
            <div class="radio radio-success form-check-inline">
              <%= form.radio_button :exclusion, true %>
              <label for="scope_exclusion_true"> Yes </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-danger form-check-inline">
              <%= form.radio_button :exclusion, false %>
              <label for="scope_exclusion_false"> No </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when it gets to the controller, the parameters look like this:

```
 {"exclusion"=>"false"}
```

However, this doesn't seem to make it to the database, although there isn't any error. For example,

```
2.5.8 :014 > Scope.last.update(exclusion: "true")
  Scope Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "scopes".* FROM "scopes" ORDER BY "scopes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Scope Update (0.8ms)  UPDATE "scopes" SET "exclusion" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "scopes"."id" = $3  [["exclusion", 0], ["updated_at", "2020-06-03 17:44:18.296337"], ["id", 1057]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.5.8 :015 > Scope.last.exclusion
  Scope Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "scopes".* FROM "scopes" ORDER BY "scopes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 0
2.5.8 :016 >
```

This doesn't work, but if I pass the value `true` instead of `"true"`, then it works, as shown below:

```
2.5.8 :016 > Scope.last.update(exclusion: true)
  Scope Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "scopes".* FROM "scopes" ORDER BY "scopes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  Scope Update (0.7ms)  UPDATE "scopes" SET "exclusion" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "scopes"."id" = $3  [["exclusion", 1], ["updated_at", "2020-06-03 17:44:43.940131"], ["id", 1057]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.5.8 :017 > Scope.last.exclusion
  Scope Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "scopes".* FROM "scopes" ORDER BY "scopes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 1
```

How do I adjust my HTML form so that it actually passes a boolean `true` or `false` rather than `"true"` or `"false"`?

Comment: `<%= form.radio_button :exclusion, false %>` It looks like your value here is being set as: "false".  View the Source to see how your form is being presented to the browser. To fix the solution you can just as easily get true or false variables comparing strings.  `params[:exclusion].eql?("false") ? nil : nil`

Answer (score 1):

By changing the values from `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`, that seems to solve my problem. I realized that the database fields aren't set to booleans, but actual integers and so that explains why:

```
        <div class="form-group row">
          <%= form.label :exclusion, class: "col-sm-3 col-form-label", for: 'scope_exclusion' %>
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9 col-12 pt-2 pl-3">
            <div class="radio radio-success form-check-inline">
              <%= form.radio_button :exclusion, "1" %>
              <label for="scope_exclusion_true"> Yes </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-danger form-check-inline">
              <%= form.radio_button :exclusion, "2" %>
              <label for="scope_exclusion_false"> No </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```